# Series expansion of $\int x^xdx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

The indefinite integral: 
$$J=\int x^xdx$$
has no known closed form solution.
Expanding in series the function $f=x^x$ we get:
$$f\simeq\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{x^k\ln(x)^k}{k!}$$
So we can write:
$$J\simeq\sum_{k=0}^N\int\dfrac{x^k\ln(x)^k}{k!}dx$$
and we get:
$$J\simeq x+\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{\ln(x)^k\left[-(k+1)\ln(x)\right]^{-k}\Gamma\left(k+1,-(k+1)\ln(x)\right)}{(k+1)!}$$
where $\Gamma(x,a)$ is the incomplete gamma function.
It seems to work well in approximating J, for $N\ge 20$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Is there a better way to calculate numerically $J$ avoiding the use of the usual methods to evaluate definite integrals? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use $\frac{k!x^{k+1}}{k+1}\sum\limits_{v=0}^k\frac{(-1)^v(\ln x)^{k-v}}{(k+1)^v(k-v)!}$ for $\int\limits_{}^{}x^k(\ln x)^k$ instead of the incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int x^x~dx=\int e^{x\ln x}~dx=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n(\ln x)^n}{n!}dx$

For $\int x^n(\ln x)^n~dx$ , where $n$ is any non-negative integers,

$\int x^n(\ln x)^n~dx$

$=\int(\ln x)^n~d\left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}d((\ln x)^n)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)x}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{nx^n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{n+1}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\int\dfrac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{n+1}d\left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\int\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}d\left(\dfrac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{n+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\int\dfrac{n(n-1)x^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-2}}{(n+1)^2x}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\int\dfrac{n(n-1)x^n(\ln x)^{n-2}}{(n+1)^2}dx$

$=\cdots\cdots$

$\vdots$

$\vdots$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times2)x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^n}-\int\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times1)x^n}{(n+1)^n}dx$

$=\dfrac{x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{n+1}-\dfrac{nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times2)x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^n}+\dfrac{(-1)^n(n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times1)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}+C$

$=\dfrac{(n+1)x^{n+1}(\ln x)^n}{(n+1)^2}-\dfrac{(n+1)nx^{n+1}(\ln x)^{n-1}}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}((n+1)n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times2)x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^{n+1}}+\dfrac{(-1)^n((n+1)n(n-1)\cdots\cdots\times1)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(n+1)!x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+2}}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}n!x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$

$\therefore\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(x\ln x)}{n!}dx=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$

Hence $\int x^x~dx=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}x^{n+1}(\ln x)^k}{k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the integral as

$\displaystyle I=\int x^x d x=\int e^{x \ln x} d x\tag*{} $
Using the definition of $e^y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{n !}$, we have
$\displaystyle I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n !} \int x^n \ln ^n x d x\tag*{} $

Using the substitution $x=e^{-\frac{z}{n+1}}$ to further transform the integral into

$\displaystyle I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n !(n+1)^{n+1}} \int e^{-z} z^n d z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1) !n^{n}} \int e^{-z} z^{n-1} d z\tag*{} $

Using the incomplete Gamma function,

$\displaystyle \int e^{-z} z^{n-1} d z=-\Gamma(n,z)\tag*{} $

we can express $I$ as

$\displaystyle \boxed{I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \Gamma(n, -(n+1)\ln x)}{(n-1) ! n ^n}}\tag*{} $

---

In particular, if the integral has limits $0$ and $1$, we have

$\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^{1} x^x d x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \Gamma(n, 0)}{(n-1) ! n^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}}\tag*{} $

Using the same approach, we have
$\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{ x^{x} }d x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}}\tag*{}$